# New to Flexbox - what do I need to do?

Tags: css, flexbox

The code has three divs that are ordered in the dom by div-00#

What I'd like to create using flexbox (for width >= 460px) is the following layout (please see images)
[image]
Added: 18-12-16 - 
[image]
is anyone able to suggest how to do this using flexbox?

There is a second issue with the tab order but would appreciate sorting the layout first.

ON MOBILE (say < 460px) - within the .div-main:
All the divs are 100% of the parent div, ordered .div-001 -div-002 .div-003.

ON DESKTOP (say >= 460px) - within the .div-main:
Because of varying heights I'm not using floats, as this happens on desktop
[image: Using floats].

.div-001 -- Position: Top Right. Height: Varying. Width: 20%. Ideally the tab index should be 2 (therefore I've used flex to order this '2') but know that the order is read out by the order of the DOM.

.div-002 -- Position: Top Left. Height: Varying. Width: 80%. Ideally the tab index should be 1 (therefore I've used flex to order this '1')

.div-003 -- Position: Right (Directly below .div-003). Height: Varying. Width: 20%. Ideally the tab index should be 3 (therefore I've used flex to order this '3')

The order (just in case you were wondering) is important.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
a:focus,
 a:hover {
  color: red;
}
.header,
.footer {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1220px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #000;
}
.header {
  height: 50px;
}
.footer {
  height: 20px;
}
.div-main {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
.div-main > div { 
  min-height: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  padding: 10px;
}
@media all and (min-width: 460px) {
  .div-main {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .div-desktop-left {
    width: 80%;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
  .div-desktop-right {
    width: 20%;
    margin-left: auto;
  }
  .div-001 {
    /* example */
    height: 70px;
    order: 2;
  }
  .div-002 {
    /* example (varying height) */
    align-self: flex-start;
    /* smaller than .div-001 */
    height: 50px;
    /* bigger than .div-001 */
    /* height: 360px; */
    order: 1;
  }
  .div-003 {
    /* example */
    height: 20px;
    order: 3;
  }
}
```

```html
<header class="header"></header>
<div class="div-main">
  <div class="div-001 div-mobile-001 div-desktop-002 div-desktop-right div-desktop-right-001"><a href="#">Desktop link 002</a></div>
  <div class="div-002 div-mobile-002 div-desktop-001 div-desktop-left div-desktop-left-001"><a href="#">Desktop link 001</a></div>
  <div class="div-003 div-mobile-003 div-desktop-003 div-desktop-right div-desktop-right-002"><a href="#">Desktop link 003</a></div>
</div>
<footer class="footer"></footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't figure it out with flexbox,

Heres a solution using CSS Grid if you're not technology restricted:

HTML

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 3fr 1fr;
  height: 300px;
  
}

.box {
  border: 5px solid red;
  padding: 50px;
  
  
}

.box.three {
  grid-column: 2;
}

@media (max-width: 460px) {
  main {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
  }
  .box {
    border-color: black;
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
          <meta charset="UTF-8">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
          <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
          <title>Flexer</title>
        </head>
        <body>
          <main>
            <div class="box one">one</div>
            <div class="box two">two</div>
            <div class="box three">three</div>
          </main>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Almost! The divs can all be of varying height - .div-001 (top right) can be smaller than .div-002 (top left). The way you suggest means (I think ) that .div-003 sits immediately below both .div-001 and .div-002 - also I'm not sure on how the widths work with grid

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with giving .div-main a flex-direction: column by doing that .div-desktop-left and .div-desktop-right will not align next to each other what you need change is to give .div-main flex-direction: row and flex-wrap: wrap and that will solve the problem

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
a:focus,
 a:hover {
  color: red;
}
.header,
.footer {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1220px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #000;
}
.header {
  height: 50px;
}
.footer {
  height: 20px;
}
.div-main {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
.div-main > div { 
  min-height: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  padding: 10px;
}
@media all and (min-width: 460px) {
  .div-main {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
  }
  .div-desktop-left {
    width: 80%;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
  .div-desktop-right {
    width: 20%;
    margin-left: auto;
  }
  .div-001 {
    /* example */
    height: 70px;
    order: 2;
  }
  .div-002 {
    /* example */
    align-self: flex-start;
    height: 50px;
    order: 1;
  }
  .div-003 {
    /* example */
    height: 20px;
    order: 3;
  }
}
```

```html
<header class="header"></header>
<div class="div-main">
  <div class="div-001 div-mobile-001 div-desktop-002 div-desktop-right div-desktop-right-001"><a href="#">Desktop link 002</a></div>
  <div class="div-002 div-mobile-002 div-desktop-001 div-desktop-left div-desktop-left-001"><a href="#">Desktop link 001</a></div>
  <div class="div-003 div-mobile-003 div-desktop-003 div-desktop-right div-desktop-right-002"><a href="#">Desktop link 003</a></div>
</div>
<footer class="footer"></footer>
```

Comment: Hi Sara, again Almost - .On Mobile: div-001 is first, .div-002 is second, .div-003 is third

- On Desktop: .div-002 is top left, .div-001 is top right, .div-003 is right (directly underneath of .div-001)

- Your solution means: div-001 is top left, .div-002 is top right, .div-003 is right (directly underneath of .div-001).

This could also be done with floats.

Comment: Hi Sara, again almost - The problem is that if .div-002 is greater in height than .div-001 then .div-003 does not sit directly below .div-001 instead it sits below the bottom of .div-002 on desktop

I wanted the divs on the right to sit directly below (please see update, the second image)

Comment: I can't figure it out but you can apply a negative margin-top to  div-003 to turn around this problem and if that not accepted consider using CSS grid.